# Handler delay not considered android

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I'm using a `Handler` to have a delay in my app but seems not works. The whole procedure is in a service because i need check when the screen goes off. In my MainActivity i get this part of code with a switch:

```
//attach a listener to check for changes in state
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                             boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked){
                        LayoutInflater l = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                        View dview = l.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        ad.setView(dview);
                        final EditText edit = (EditText) dview.findViewById(R.id.edit);

                        ad.setCancelable(false)
                            .setTitle("Set minutes")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                                    String e = edit.getText().toString();
                                    if(e!=null && !e.isEmpty()){
                                        try{
                                            n = Integer.parseInt(e);
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                            n=0;
                                        }
                                    }   
                                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class));
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                        AlertDialog alertD = ad.create();

                        alertD.show();


                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.twixkat.twixconnection", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("switchstate", true);
                        editor.commit();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Stopped ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class));
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.twixkat.twixconnection", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("switchstate", false);
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                }
            });
```

That simply creates a dialog to ask how much minutes has to pass. So i can set the delay manually taking the value from edittext in the dialog. (In my case `n`). After that i have the real code in the service:

```
@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
        // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service partito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    screen();
                }
            }, (m.n / 1000) / 60);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void screen(){
        IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        intent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        wifimanager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i){
                    if (i.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                        Toast.makeText(AlarmReceiver.this, "Screen off, wifi off ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);

                    } else if (i.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                        Toast.makeText(AlarmReceiver.this, "Screen on...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, intent);
    }
```

Where `m.n` is the value of edittext because i can't create the dialog in the service. The problem is that the `screen()` method starts when the screen goes off and without waiting the delay. Actually i can't find any other solution to my problem..

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass milliseconds to the `postDelayed` method so you should multiply your `m.n` value so change

```
(m.n / 1000) / 60
```

to

```
(m.n * 1000) * 60
```

which will give you the minutes entered by user in milliseconds

Comment: But, users in the edittext have to set  time in milliseconds? Isn't possible set in the edittext for example "5" that are 5 minutes? instead 5000 i mean

Comment: Anyway, seems not consider the Handler..Even if i write 100000000 milliseconds. It fires the method immediately

Comment: m.n / 1000 / 60 = 1600ms.

Comment: @mihail but how can i have the minutes? And, is it correct the service? I put the code in the `onStart()` method but i don't know if it's correct

Comment: I found something like: `((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);` but i'm not sure.. now i try

Comment: That's what the multiplication does, change minutes to milliseconds. For eg. if the user entered 5 minutes then you multiply it by 60 to get seconds and then multiply it by 1000 again to get milliseconds. Which toast is being displayed when the `Service` is called?

Comment: 1 minute has 60 seconds, 1 second has 1000 milliseconds. If you enter data in minutes you have to convert in in milliseconds - **minutes*60*1000**

Comment: mmh..maybe i understand the problem.. I mean..i want that the Handler "understand" that if i write in the edittext "5" are 5 minutes.. the user can't write "60000" in the edittext! but 1 if wants a minute.. right? so in this way could work?

Comment: I created a Toast and the value it's correct.. 5 seconds = 300.000 milliseconds... But the method starts only for the first time.. then it fires always immediatelly..